# UnicodeDecodeError when installing mutagen pip

Tags: python, pip, mutagen

So I wanted to install the pip 'mutagen' on my PC.
I using python 3.6.
When I tried to install the pip on my PC, I got this error:

```
    Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\אלי\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 38: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\אלי\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\אלי\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Users\אלי\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\אלי\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "C:\Users\אלי\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "C:\Users\אלי\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 38: invalid continuation byte
```

I using windows 10 and my default language is Hebrew.
I tried to install mutagen on other computers and I succeed.
Do anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm guessing the Hebrew string in your user name is using your local code page, and that it isn't Unicode-compatible. Does it work if you install to a different folder (say, create a `virtualenv` in `C:\temp` or whatever location works with a modern Windows)?

Comment: Thank you tripleee, I succeed.

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug in `pip` or in your set-up. I'd guess the `pip` maintainers will be reluctant to "fix" it even if it's technically on their turf, so changing your environment might be the easiest workaround by far. Maybe you can update your environment to Unicode-compatible and still keep your localized user name? (Perhaps my naïvety is shining through here; I stopped using Windows long ago.)